# gogo.proto: File not found

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

`protoc --gogofaster_out=. image.proto`

I get this error message

> /home/abc/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto: File not found.
>
> image.proto: Import "/home/abc/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto" was not found or had errors.

The file is definitely there. I can reach it from the reported path in the error.

My proto file looks like this:

```
package image;

import "/home/abc/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";

message Frame {
required bool fragment = 1; 
required int32  fragmentID = 2; 
required bool lastFragment = 3; 
required bytes data = 4;
}
```

I have a `Makefile` in the dir where the proto file is. Looks like this:

```
regenerate:
--proto_path=../../github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto:../../github.com/gogo/protobuf/protobuf/google/protobuf:. --gogofaster_out=. *.proto
```

What can I do to resolve the path error?

Answer (score 1):

As [in this issue](http://protoc%20--gogofaster_out), you could try and import only the relative path:

```
import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";
```

Make sure that `GOPATH` is set to `/home/abc` first.

I mention [protobuf PR 241](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/pull/241/files), where the makefile defines the PATH to use:

```
regenerate: 
  protoc-min-version --version="3.0.0" 
    --proto_path=$(GOPATH)/src/image:
                 $(GOPATH)/src/github.com/go‌​go/protobuf/protobuf‌​:
                 $(GOPATH)/src/githu‌​b.com/gogo/protobuf/‌​protobuf/google/prot‌​obuf:
                 . --gogo_out=. *.proto
```

The OP mention [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gogoprotobuf/PuSSI8QvMjQ), which points out:

> The dependencies call other dependencies in "`google/protobuf/`", so these need to be in the path correctly also.
>   The errors are pretty misleading
>
> Also when using gogoproto extensions you should use `gogofast_out`.
>   `gofast_out` is only for when you are not using any extensions, but want some extra speed.
>   `gogofast_out` / `gofast_out` has no side effects.
>   `gogofaster_out` makes most fields `nullable=false`.

Comment: Relative path same error. The link to the issue you posted does not work for me.

Comment: @user3017869  is GOPATH properly set? What version of Go are you using? Is the path and file `/home/abc/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto` accessible and readable?

Comment: `GOPATH` is set correctly. Go version is 1.8. gogo.proto is accessible and readable

Comment: In your Makefile, you you use GOPATH instead of releative path? (as in https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/pull/241/files)

Comment: I was not. I changed it to no effect. Here is how the `Makefile` looks now.

`regenerate:                                                                                                            protoc-min-version --version="3.0.0" --proto_path=$(GOPATH)/src/image:$(GOPATH)/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/protobuf:$(GOPATH)/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/protobuf/google/protobuf:. --gogo_out=. *.proto`
This guy here seems to have solved it, but he did not leave many clues on how.
[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gogoprotobuf/PuSSI8QvMjQ)

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `go get -u github.com/gogo/protobuf` to download the dependencies to local directory `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`
2. Run `go mod vendor` to packaging your module dependencies. After execute this cmd, there should be a directory "vendor" in your project and shall be referred in the Makefile.

The Makefile command should be:

```
regenerate: 
    protoc-min-version --version="3.0.0" \
    --proto_path=$(GOPATH)/src/image \
    -I vendor/github.com/go‌​go/protobuf/protobuf‌​ \
    -I vendor/githu‌​b.com/gogo/protobuf/‌​protobuf/google/prot‌​obuf \
    -I. --gogo_out=. *.proto
```

Here, --pro_path and -I are the same.
In case the absolute path contains variable then the pattern should be:

```
-I=${path_variable}/a/sample \
-I=${path_variable}/b/sample \
```

Hope this might help someone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the gogo.proto directory to search for imports using `--proto_path` parameter.

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
--go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
path/to/your/target/protofile --proto_path=$GOPATH/src/ --proto_path=.
```